# In AsyncTask the item are not updated?

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I am getting the bug in below code any one suggest me how we can resolve this issue...

Here is my code::

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        reviewText = etReviews.getText().toString();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(reviewText)) {


            new ReviewUpdateTask().execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write the Review",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


private class ReviewUpdateTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new Dialog(act);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loader_view);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (dialog.isShowing())
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
            }
            try {
                JSONArray arr = AppConstants.reviewInfoObj
                        .getJSONArray("userReviews");
                adapter = new MyReviewAdapter(ReviewActivity.this, arr);
                lvReviews.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {


                    String response = Data.postData(obj, AppConstants.urlReviewUpdate);
                    AppConstants.reviewInfoObj = constructReviewData();


            return null;
        }

        private JSONObject constructReviewData() {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = AppConstants.reviewInfoObj;
                JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("userReviews");
                //
                obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("uRating", ratedValue);
                obj.put("uLike", "yes");
                obj.put("uDisLike", "no");
                obj.put("uPlace", address);
                obj.put("uDateTime", currentDateandTime);
                obj.put("uReview", reviewText);
                arr.put(obj);
                obj.put("userReviews", arr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return obj;
        }

    }
```

first click its working fine,when i entered new text in review edit text and i am getting force close

the Exception is:

```
 android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.appdest.labelleza.ReviewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{426e2cb0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-350,250} that was originally added here
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:256)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:291)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at com.appdest.labelleza.ReviewActivity$ReviewUpdateTask.onPreExecute(ReviewActivity.java:245)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at com.appdest.labelleza.ReviewActivity.onClick(ReviewActivity.java:207)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18599)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
    06-01 18:53:42.262: E/WindowManager(4142):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any one suggest me how I can resolve this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

As you're showing dialog in the `onPreExecute()` method your AsyncTask holds reference to your activity. And this is the way you get memory leak, that's why you got Exception. One solution is make your dialog class member of your activity and dismiss it in during the `onPause()`.

Consider reading [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dialog is set to null on activity's onPause and check if its null onPostExecute before attempting to invoke methods on it.